# Is there a regexp_replace equivalent for postgresql 7.4?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to use `SELECT regexp_replace(m.*, '[\n\r]+', ' ', 'g')` to remove carriage returns and new lines from my field to generate a CSV from my table; however, looks like my postgresql version (7.4.27) does not support that function.

> function regexp_replace(members, "unknown", "unknown", "unknown") does not exist

I also tried doing it this way:

```
SELECT replace(replace(m.*, '\r', ''), '\n', '')
```

> function replace(members, "unknown", "unknown") does not exist
>
> No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

or this way:

```
SELECT replace(replace(m.*, chr(13), ''), chr(10), '')
```

> function replace(members, text, "unknown") does not exist

and still got similar errors.

How can a achieve that using another function or solution?

Comment: You can always upgrade. 7.x shouldn't be used any more.

Comment: It's not under my control to upgrade this database unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m.*` makes no sense where you put it. It would work like this:

```
SELECT replace(replace(m.some_column, chr(13), ''), chr(10), '')
FROM   tbl m;
```

But that just removes all "linefeed" and "carriage return" characters completely instead of replacing each string consisting only of these characters with a single space character like your original. If that's what you want, single character replacement is simpler and cheaper with `translate()` - also available in ancient pg 7.4:

```
SELECT translate(some_column, chr(13) || chr(10), '');
```

To achieve what your original `regexp_replace()` does (just without the nonsensical `m.*`), identify a single character that's not in the string and use that as stepping stone. Say: `°` does not pop up, then:

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(
        translate(some_column, chr(13) || chr(10), '°')  -- replace with dummy
      , '°°', '°')  -- consolidate to single dummy
      , '°°', '°')  -- repeat as many times as necessary
      , '°', ' ');  -- replace dummy with space
```

Looks awkward, and it's imperfect: fails for too many consecutive line breaks. But it's probably still faster than `regexp_replace()`, even in modern Postgres, because regular expressions are much more expensive. Then again, performance is probably not an issue here.

Upgrade to modern Postgres and you don't need this.